# New method to find distance between 2 points

Tags: iphone, location, distance

I was using following code to find distance between 2 points:

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.3636 longitude:-77.1212];

CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:42.353297 longitude:-71.578858];

float target = [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2];
```

But now getDistanceFrom is deprecated  by Apple.

What should I try to perform same task?

Comment: Try consulting the official documentation a bit more thorough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `-distanceFromLocation:` instead? It's even explicitly mentioned in the documentation on `-getDistanceFrom:` as the method to use as a replacement.

Comment: will you please tell me how to set that CLLocationDistance object that this method returns....for my CLLocation object (here location1)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use 'distanceFromLocation:'. See the documentation for more: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html